# What do all the walls with secret switches look like?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

Some walls have non-obvious switches hidden in them, that the player can activate and which occasionally reveal secrets and provide loot. We're introduced to the wall with a loose rock in the first level of the dungeon, but are there others? If so, what do they look like? Hand-drawn circles around the switch "hotspot" and any other obvious identifying feature preferred.

Comment: I dreamed wall of stones and rocks all the night, crazy!

Comment: They look like they are out of place. You have to look really carefully into the details.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Where a switch type appears on a wall is variable, so while the screenshots below circle what the switch looks like, it doesn't mean you can always look at exactly that part of the wall to see it.

---

Here are the hidden switch types I've seen.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

---

Also, I have found secrets by doing the following:

- Placing torches in sconces
- Removing torches from sconces
- Finding pressure plates on the floors (which have always been very obvious)
- Placing desired item types in alcoves (such as putting a weapon in the alcove outside the room that says "no weapons allowed")
- Slicing tapestries hanging on walls to cut them down and reveal switches behind them.

Comment: Omg at 4th switch,so hard to notice since it's so freaking tiny.

Comment: I've now completed the game, but was missing 10 secrets. So it's possible there's a switch type that I don't have a picture of, but I'm betting it is just those four.

Comment: you missed 2 buttons but here's a free hint, they don't look like buttons look at the companies name logo for a clue :)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/umDpt.jpg

Comment: Can you please edit the answer to contain all the buttons?